# How to change text color of AppBar, icon color of FAB universally using theme?

Tags: flutter

I am able to set the background color of `AppBar` to `Colors.amber`. This automatically sets the text color to Black. I am aware of the accessibility issues that may arise but anyways I want the text color to be White.

I am still able to set the text color from the `AppBar` but I would like to set it universally.

Here's the theme I'm using for my app.

```
title: 'Flutter Demo',
theme: new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
  textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
    bodyColor: Colors.white,
    displayColor: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

Comment: You can create your own custom appBar by extending AppBar class and then use it everywhere

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way of doing this is to adjust the title color for the theme that you are working with:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
    headline6: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: This solution is not valid anymore since the error triggered is the following: 'title' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline6. This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8..
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Comment: How do you know AppBar uses `headline6`? Is there a documentation..?
If there is, can you point ??

Comment: @Ramesh-X documentation for headline6 "Used for the primary text in app bars and dialogs (e.g., AppBar.title and AlertDialog.title)" source : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline6.html

Comment: Perhaps due to being an old answer, this is not the best solution nowadays. There is a separate appBarTheme property on the theme that allows customization of only AppBars instead of the entire headline6 property everywhere.

Answer (score 86):

I used a slightly different technique, I didn't use a theme, I just customized its appearance, so that when I created it looked like this:

```
appBar: new AppBar(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.white
  ),
  title: const Text('Saved Suggestions', style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white
  )),
  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
),
```

Comment: That works for a one off, but the OP specifically asked how do do this universally using a Theme.

Answer (score 39):

So far the solution I tested is using a **foregroundColor** in **appBarTheme**

This worked fine for me Universally

```
MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white //here you can give the text color
          )
     )
)
```

[image]

```
MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black//here you can give the text color
          )
     )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Finally this helped me.

Comment: Great! Exactly what's needed.

Comment: Best answer, `AppBarTheme.titleTextStyle` gives me wrong text size

Answer (score 16):

Here is the way you can set the AppBar Title color.

```
return new MaterialApp(
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      accentIconTheme: Theme.of(context).accentIconTheme.copyWith(
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      accentColor: Colors.amber,
      primaryColor: Colors.amber,
      primaryIconTheme: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.copyWith(
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      primaryTextTheme: Theme
          .of(context)
          .primaryTextTheme
          .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white)),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Theme Demo"),
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 13):

I will write what the change in the property of `ThemeData` affects.

The content written here is a way that does not affect other widgets as much as possible.

If you want to change the color of appbar's title,

```
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
    title: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white
    )
  ),
```

If you want to change the icon color of the appbar,

```
  primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData.fallback().copyWith(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
```

If you want to change icon color of FAB.

```
  accentIconTheme: const IconThemeData.fallback().copyWith(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
```

In addition, when you want to change the color of FAB.
It is impossible only by the property of ThemeData.
So you need to specify it directly. However, it would be better to use `Theme.of(context)`.

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
```

Comment: `TextTheme.title` is called `TextTheme.headline6` now

Comment: `TextTheme.headline6` changes the default fontsize of appbar to the smaller one

Answer (score 6):

After updating to Flutter 2.5.1 stable channel

They added a lot of updates to the theme. Also, you almost can theme everything
for the float action button and app bar use the following attributes ..

```
ThemeData(
        floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
            foregroundColor: Coolor.FLOAT_ACTION_BTN_ICON,
            backgroundColor: Coolor.FLOAT_ACTION_BTN_BACKGROUND),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Coolor.APP_BLUE),
            backgroundColor: Coolor.WHITE,
            foregroundColor: Coolor.APP_BLUE));
```

and in your material app widget, you can pass the theme we have just implemented.

```
MaterialApp(
        title: 'FMS',
        theme: your_theme);
```

Hoping that helped.

Answer (score 4):

In the widget that runs when you first call main.dart file, you can add a named parameter theme which enables you to add global styles

In the build method of the widget,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: _buildLightTheme(),
    title: 'title of app',
    home: LoginPage(app: app),
    initialRoute: '/login',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      "/login": (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(app: app,)
    });
 }
```

Here I have created a separate method for my themes called _buildLightTheme

```
ThemeData _buildLightTheme() {
   final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
    return base.copyWith(
     accentColor: kUndaGreen,
     scaffoldBackgroundColor: kUndaWhite,
     cardColor: Colors.white,
     textSelectionColor: Colors.amberAccent,
     errorColor: Colors.green,
     textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.black,
    appBarTheme:_appBarTheme()
   );
}
```

For the appBarTheme I have a separate method _appBarTheme

```
AppBarTheme _appBarTheme(){
  return AppBarTheme( 
     elevation: 0.0,
     color: kUndaGreen,
     iconTheme: IconThemeData(
       color: Colors.white,
     ),);
 }
```

Comment: I didn't know `AppBarTheme` was a thing, this helped immensely. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can set it with AppBarTheme

```dart
theme: new ThemeData(
  textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        // center text style
        headline6: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black
        ),
        // Side text style
        bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
      )
    )
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

`title` of `AppBar` uses `headline6` and `floatingActionBar` uses color from `primarySwatch`. Though it is not documented in `TextTheme`, but I tested it. For example : to have red `FloatingActionButton` and blue title text in `AppBar` your `theme` inside `MaterialApp` should look like the following :

```
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(            
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 28.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy and efficient and, less code method. Use light theme with desired color.

```
theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    accentColor: Colors.amber,
    primaryColor: Colors.amber,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I wanna let u know that there are 3 ways to set colors in flutter.

So u asked u wanna set color or text in app bar. So it works if u set color in style property of Text method. Let me show you how it works. And also I will show you 3 ways of setting color. It doesn't matter if u use theme property or not because setting color of Text works as diffrent. Thats way I didn't use Theme property in examples.

1th:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App Name",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.colorname),);
```

2th :

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App Name",
    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffffff),));
```

3th :

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text("App Name",
    style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),));
```

Comment: the question is about how to set the color universally. This is not the solution for that

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for me:

```
  theme: ThemeData(
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
    headline6: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue,
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are smart developer then you will also try this code

```
 appBar: AppBar(

    title: const Text("Layout Project" , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
    leading: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black,),
    actions: const [
      Icon(Icons.file_upload),
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.black,),),
      Icon(Icons.more_vert,color: Colors.black,)
    ],
    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
  ) ,
```

Comment: This is very obvious, however the author asks to change from ThemeData

Answer (score 0):

Just use appbar theme :
ThemeData(
useMaterial3: true,
primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(foregroundColor: Colors.white),
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
shadowColor: Colors.black,
textTheme: Theme.of(context)
.textTheme
.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.3, displayColor: Colors.white),

```
    // textTheme: TextTheme(titleLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  ),
```

Comment: This answer is already in the topic. If you think it's slightly deprecated, like only parameter change, please edit the correct answer.