# ThemeData - deprecated title argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to find an answer for the question "how to correctly code the depreciated 'title' argument of ThemeData?" (I am following a tutorial). However I found the correct answer bewteen some comments in other topic. I leave the answer below for future references and an easy finding.

```
theme: new ThemeData(
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      title: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
))),
```

[How to change text color of AppBar, icon color of FAB universally using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619848/how-to-change-text-color-of-appbar-icon-color-of-fab-universally-using-theme/53463604)

Answer by eMarine: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584407/emarine

Answer (score 17):

That is now deprecated, this giving message which itself says what to use

> '`title` is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The
> modern term is `headline6`. '
> 'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'

**Example:**

```
ThemeData(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                headline6: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: _customColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              ),
      ),
```

Similarly,

Other parameters are also been deprecated. So, now we have to use the right ones which are mentioned below:

```
display4 => headline1;
display3 => headline2;
display2 => headline3;
display1 => headline4;
headline => headline5;
title    => headline6;
subhead  => subtitle1;
subtitle => subtitle2;
body2    => bodyText1;
body     => bodyText2;
```

Answer (score 9):

Replace 'title' for 'headline6':

```
theme: new ThemeData(
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      headline6: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
))),
```