# AppBar text color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I’m setting `primarySwatch: Colors.blue`, I’m getting white texts in AppBar.
However, when I’m switching to `primarySwatch: Colors.cyan`, texts are black.

I guess, Google does some kind of magic and automatically adjusts it.
How to globally edit theme to show always white texts in AppBar (for title and tabs).

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52804265/10860596

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and see if that works

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text(
    'History',
    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffffffaa)),
  ),
),
```

Comment: That's why I said `How to globally`. I would like to specify text color in a single place, and not only for the title but also for tabs, etc.