# how to change color of text and icons on appbar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having problem while changing the color of text and icon widgets on appbar in flutter.

I have tried theme inside the material app but it's not working.

where this is working : `title: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),`
But I want to apply this for all appbars. So where should I make changes in material theme.

```
MaterialApp(
          title: "My App",
          theme: ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xffFCD581),
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
            ),
```

[image]

how can i change the color of `text: profile` and `icon` . globally.

setting color of `headline6` to `Colors.black` works. but it's also making the title text smaller. I can set the fontsize in `headline6` and it reflects universally.
But I think the default size of title that we get with appbar is suitable enough. So is there any solution that will only change the `color` of the `appbar text, title` without affecting the `fontsize`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text color of AppBar, icon color of FAB universally using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619848/how-to-change-text-color-of-appbar-icon-color-of-fab-universally-using-theme)

Comment: no actually. It's not working now. some solutions works like setting color of `headline6 : Colors.black` but it also changing the fontsize to the smaller one. Though we can set the fontsize for appbar universally there but I want the fontsize as it was default previously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `IconButton` as the back button and assign color, for Title use `TextStyle` and assign a color.

**1. Using AppBar:**

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.red),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        title: Text("Sample", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
```

**2. Using ThemeData:**

```
theme: ThemeData(
    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
    ),
  ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I know this. but I need to this for every appbar. How I can apply this globally to all appbars. ? I had done it previously but now I don't know why it's not working this time

Comment: for `headline6` it's working. but the issue is now we need to provide the `fontsize` and if we don't give `fontsize` it's default is too small. But the default size of appbar title is perfect that's now overriding.

Comment: added primaryTextTheme, this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `iconTheme` and `titleTextStyle` properties of your `AppBarTheme` in your `MaterialApp` widget.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
                appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.green),
),
```

Comment: `iconTheme` worked for icon. but `titleTextStyle` is not working. also i'm not overriding these properties in my appbar. in my `AppBar` I have only given `title` and `Icon`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change the color of text and icons:

```
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        centerTitle: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: myCustomIconColor), //ICONS
        titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
           textStyle: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 23,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
           color: myCustomTextColor,    //TEXT
         ),
        ),
        title: Text('Settings'),
      ),
```

Or you can style the `Text` widget directly and change the color there