# How do you get the color used by the icons/font at the status bar?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how do you get the icon/font color used at the status bar?

`SystemUiOverlayStyle` provides `statusBarIconBrightness` to set the icons bright or dark, but how do you get the actually used color?

Comment: It is defined in the Theme. Do you want to set the color? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518082/12098106

Comment: @Dabbel,  I'd like to apply the font/icon color from the status bar to other parts of UI - without explicitly setting the status bar's font/icon color. As a workaround, some constant value would do, but that's likely to cause inconsistent results across devices/os's, so reading the actually used color would be preferred. That is, if there's an api for this...